# Having trouble URL mapping using Django for Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, url-mapping

I am having a trouble mapping urls correctly. I've included my code below.

I am able to run the code just fine, but when I click the "about" hyperlink, I get an error saying

> The current URL, rango/about/, didn't match any of these.

When I put in the URL just "rango/", removing the "about", I get the following error:

> The current URL, rango/, didn't match any of these.

I am a complete beginner with Django and have been going through the Tango with Django book, but currently stuck with the exercises on Ch3.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

**tango_with_django_project.urls.py**

```html
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from rango import views, urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^rango/',include('rango.urls')),
    # above maps any URLs starting with rango/ to
    # be handled by the rango application
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**rango.urls.py**

```html
from django.conf.urls import url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    url(r'^rango/', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'$^rango/about/',views.about,name='about'),

]
```

**rango.views.py**

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says hey there partner! \
        <br/> <a href='/rango/about/'>about</a>")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says here is the about page. \
        <br/> <a href='/rango/'>index</a>")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# rango.urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$',views.about,name='about'),
]
```